# Invalid deployment target of the framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dependencies, version

I want to decrease the framework deployment target from iOS 10 to iOS 9. I did the fork of the library, changed deployment target of the framework TARGET (not whole project). When I build the dependency I can see in info.plist that deployment target is iOS 9 (screenshots attached) in the framework and iOS 8 in the framework's dependency. Anyway, my project where I attach those still outputs that iOS 10 is required for this framework (yes, i did clean, delete derived data, change simulator, reset xcode).

> .../MyFile.swift:13:8: Module file's minimum deployment target is ios10.0 v10.0:
>   .../MapFramework.framework/Modules/MapFramework.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule

(that's in Swift file in the line where I have `import MapFramework`)

[image: framework info.plist screenshot]
[image: framework dependency info plist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was happening, because by mistake, there were two copies of the same .framework in the file hierarchy. One was in Carthage folder, another one in root folder. Even though marking in `Xcode -> Reveal in Finder` on the framework it always shown framework in Carthage folder, somehow it was processing both of these. After removal of the framework located in root folder everything was working perfectly fine (I didn't have to change any paths or references in Xcode, what shows that Xcode all of the time was pointing to the correct version).

Seems like an Xcode bug.